# how to filter or manipulate columns of csv file using another column using python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import random

f=open("gh.csv","w")
csv.reader(f)
g=open("gh.csv","a")
k=csv.writer(g)
k.writerow(("age","ageband","gender","disease"))
for i in range(10):
    k.writerow((random.choice((range(0,100))),'40-50',random.choice(['male','female']),random.choice(['heartstroke','breastcancer','hypertension','hive'])))
for col in f:
    age=row[2]
    if 40<=age>=55:
      print '40-55'
    elif 56<=age>=75:
      print '56-75'
    elif 76<=age>=100:
      print '76-100'
    else :
      print 'age>20'    
f.close()


age ageband gender  disease
62  40-50   female  breastcancer
15  40-50   female  breastcancer
6   40-50   male    breastcancer
59  40-50   male    heartstroke
64  40-50   female  breastcancer
98  40-50   female  breastcancer
51  40-50   female  heartstroke
95  40-50   male    heartstroke
27  40-50   male    breastcancer
31  40-50   male    hypertension
```

after writing random data into csv file . is it possible to overwrite certain fields based on columns. 
 for example if the age is 35 then the age band column should be updated     as ''56-75'. and breast cancer should be  updated only for females. please i need help as i am new to python. any kind of help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you considered just building the row "correctly" in the first place instead of having hard coded values that might not make sense?  Also, as an aside, men can get breast cancer too.

Comment: by the way, I think your if/elif's should be corrected ... `40 <= age <= 55`

Comment: yeah its corrected. but i want to know how to update values ??

Comment: i am building csv file with dummy data . its just an exercise for me to improve skills  in csv manipulation. all i need is how to update csv file according to the above condition i stated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options are [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/) and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) (which is a much bigger computing library, but should have good support for this sort of thing).

Comment: thanks  for your suggestion. i will try .

Comment: Also, in Pandas, the creation of that "age band" column can be done with a function called ["cut"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html).

Comment: is it only for hard coded value ??? or any random value ??  i mean the array i.e,  pd.cut( array ( ),labels( ))